# Call click event of button who called pop up when model pop up window is closed

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I have two buttons viz. save and update. On both buttons, I am opening pop-up window using Model Pop-up extender. The Pop-up has "ok" as close button. Now what I want is when user clicks on the "Ok" button in the pop-up, it should call the OnClick_save() or OnClick_update() depends on the button who called pop-up. 
That means, when user clicks on save button, it will open pop-up window. After entering password in the pop-up window when user click on the Ok button, it should go to the OnClick_save() event. Same thing should happen for update button. How can I do so...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden controls for pop up's **OK** and **Cancel** button, and show/hide modal popup programatically. before/after doing so you can call your desired methods or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using event handler..

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
MyEventHandler handler = MyEvent;
if(handler != null)
{
    handler(this, e);

}

or

this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Or
Write a common method which can invoke from save_click event or ok_click

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know...